# stream a single audio file from the internet

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, afnetworking

I am using the AFNetworking suite in my app. In the app you can record a message, which uploads to a server. I need to be able to play that audio file either by streaming it or chaching it, an ideas on how to do either?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I would just use `AVPlayer` and load the remote URL. [Per Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayer):

> AVPlayer works equally well with local and remote media files, providing you with appropriate information about readiness to play or about the need to await additional data before continuing.

It's certainly possible to use AFNetworking to do this, but I trust that Apple's built-in `AVPlayer` will be more than suitable to your needs, and certainly worth a shot before rolling your own.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was looking in the wrong place with the AVAudioPlayer! AVPlayer works perfectly for streaming.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play a mp3 that is located on the server you can use Matt Galagher's Audiostreamer (http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/revisiting-old-post-streaming-and.html).

If you want to play a locally saved file you can use AVAudioPlayer (http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

If that is not what you want please give us some more datails.

Comment: Yeah I know about the local file but as I am recording the audio on the iPhone is it in the CAF format. This doesn't matter because it will always be played on the phone. I am using AFNetworking so would like to know if there is a fit with that. Thanks for your post.